How to display the chart on hovering a Bar HighChart
I am trying to populate a stacked barchart  on hover of To bar. Not too versed with HighChart I am finding it difficult where to start with. I tried to add the child component chart in a tooltip but its just displaying [Object,Object]. not sure if jsx is supported in a formatter function. I am adding a sandbox link .
Part(ii) - I want to add the information icon on the xAxis category as shown in hover image. How to do that ? as again my icon is jsx.
hover chart should look like

SandBox
Populated chart

     const options: Highcharts.Options = {
    chart: {
      type: 'bar',
      style: {
        marginRight: 0,
      },
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Bar Chart',
      style: {
        display: 'none',
      },
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: [
        'To',
        'Delivered',
        'Read',
        'Button Replies',
        'Failed',
        'Undelivered',
      ],
      gridLineWidth: 0,
      lineWidth: 0,
      labels: {
        enabled: true,
        style: {
          fontSize: '16px',
          color: 'black',
        },
        align: 'right',
        step: 1,
      },
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: '',
      },
      labels: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      gridLineWidth: 0,
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function () {
        // Return the HTML content of the bar chart
        return `<div id="tooltip-container">${(<StackedBarChart />)}</div>`
    },
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        pointPadding: 0.2,
        groupPadding: 0,
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          inside: false,
          style: {
            fontSize: '26px',
            color: 'black',
          },
          formatter: function () {
            console.log(this.series.name)
            console.log( this.point.y)
            if (this.series.name === 'Sent' && this.point.y ) {
              return `${this.series.name} <span>&nbsp;(${this.point.y})</span>`
            } else if (this.x === 'To') {
              return `<span>&nbsp;${4}</span>`
            } else {
              return `<span>&nbsp;${this.point.y}</span>`
            }
          },
        },
      },
    },

   

    series: [
      {
        type: 'bar',
        stacking: 'normal',
        data: [
          {
            y: 4 - 2,
            color: '#FFBE4F',
          },
          {
            y: 1,
            color: '#3CC29A',
          },
          { y: 1, color: '#64B4FA' },
          { y: 2, color: '#BCE36F' },
          { y: 0, color: '#F55868' },
          { y: 1, color: '#8C91BD' },
        ],
      },
      {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          inside: true,
          style: {
            fontSize: '14px',
            fontWeight: '450',
            color: 'black',
          },
        },
        type: 'bar',
        name: 'Sent',
        stacking: 'normal',
        data: [{ y: 2, color: '#DEDEDE' }],
      },
    ],
  }

  return (
    <div className="relative">
      <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} />
    </div>
  )


     Child Component

  const StackedBarChart = () => {
  const options: Highcharts.Options = {
    chart: {
      type: 'bar',
    },
    title: {
      text: '',
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['To'],
      gridLineWidth: 0,
      lineWidth: 0,
      labels: {
        style: {
          fontSize: '16px',
          color: 'black',
        },
      },
    },
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      title: {
        text: '',
      },
      labels: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      gridLineWidth: 0,
    },
    tooltip: {
      
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false,
    },

    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        stacking: 'normal',
        pointPadding: 0.2,
        groupPadding: 0.4,
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          style: {
            fontSize: '16px',
            color: 'black',
          },
        },
      },
    },
    series: [
      {
        type: 'bar',
        name: 'To',
        data: [
          {
            y: 4 - 2,
            color: '#FFBE4F',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        type: 'bar',
        name: 'Sent',
        stacking: 'normal',
        data: [{ y: 2, color: '#DEDEDE' }],
      },
    ],
  }

  return (
    <>
      <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} />
    </>
  )
}


I noticed that the Sandbox link you provided doesn't open. Could you please update the link?

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/barchart-66h3p8?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp - direct url . Not sure why the link is not working. Can you tell what happens when you clikc the link?
Although I have found a workaround using mantine popover . Still if some has a better idea will love to check that out.

It seems the codesandbox is private. When it comed to your question, try to use renderToStaticMarkup or portals. Useful thread: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react/issues/23

Now you should be able to access.

When it comes to rendering charts inside the tooltip, I would recommend using one of these solutions:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/highcharts-react-tooltip-forked-vkzl25?layout=%257B[…]ebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/highcharts-react-demo-fork-forked-pzl2hm?layout=%25[…]ebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/highcharts-custom-tooltip-forked-c7tfpj?file=%2Findex.tsx
